# How can I get jquery to hide menu options depending on my url?

Tags: jquery, css, menu

On my website I have a jquery code implemented that closes categories of my CSS menu depending on the the url:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('.workopen').click(function(e){
          $(this).siblings('.open').addBack().toggleClass('open');
          e.stopPropagation();
      });
      
      if (window.location.href.indexOf("glorious.html") > -1) {
            $('.work .workopen .four').siblings('.open').addBack().toggleClass('open')}
         });
```

I would like to add a bit of JQuery to alter the CSS so that a particular Div will change to "display:none;" if the above index is "glorious.html".This is probably a very simple fix, but My knowledge of JQuery is sort of limited :/ help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.workopen').click(function(e){
$(this).siblings('.open').addBack().toggleClass('open');
e.stopPropagation();
});

if (window.location.href.indexOf("glorious.html") > -1) {
$('.work .workopen .four').siblings('.open').addBack().toggleClass('open')}
$('#div1').css("display","none"); //# is used for id and . is used for class

});
```

Comment: provide menu html so that can help you exactly

Comment: Ah! I figured it would be something as simple as this, i feel stupid for have even asked. Thank you :)

Comment: quick follow up, i'm trying to specifically select a class within three respective divs to hide, this code works: $('.one .inner2').css("display","none");
$('.two .inner2').css("display","none");
$('.three .inner2').css("display","none"); but its so long, how could I condense it?

Comment: nevermind, I used:  
$('.one .inner2, .two .inner2, .three .inner2').css("display","none");